# Android Developer Name change

Tags: android, google-play

I just published my first app on the market today and put my name under developer name instead of my company name which is what it should be.  I then updated the developer name to be my company name but the change does not appear to get updated.

Does anyone know when can I expect to see the name change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at a previous posted question it toke "some time" but it will be changed in all applications.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763200/will-change-to-developer-name-affect-my-existing-apps-in-the-android-market

Comment: it is invalid link

Answer (score 3):

If you're viewing the application profile from your phone, the Market application caches a lot of stuff about viewed profiles.

You can stop/kill or clear the cache of your Android Market app in your phone and see if the name change is reflected.

Best

-serkan

Comment: If I view it from my phone it appears to be displayed correctly.  It's the website that is NOT displaying the latest change.

Answer (score 0):

it's appear on your simulator correctly most probably cause simulator is looking at the american servers .. while the computer look at your country server :)